# 1px vs thin, IE vs Excel issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, excel, width, border

I have an html table which is rendered in IE, and Excel (for reporting)

If I set the border-width to thin, it shows a 2px border in IE, and a 1px border in Excel.

However, if I set it to 1px, it shows a 1px border in IE, and a 2px border in Excel(???).

How can I get them to BOTH show a 1px border as it looks horrible with a 2px border.

Comment: sounds like "thin" causes excel to merge borders, yet 1px makes each cell 1px (thus two together=2px). Is there a "merge border" option in Excel you can flag that would allow IE to and excel to render the borders combined?

Comment: @Brad Christie, I do not know.

Comment: How do you get it to Excel? Copy Paste?

Comment: @Arnoldiusss, No, just plain html and open the file in excel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saving a excel file to html genrates CSS like so:

```
.xl32
{mso-style-parent:style0;
border-top:.5pt solid windowtext;
border-right:1.0pt solid windowtext;
border-bottom:1.0pt solid windowtext;
border-left:.5pt solid windowtext;}
```

.5 displays as a normal line, 1.0 as a thick line
So i guess setting te with to .5pt should work...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about HTML Tables rendered in Excel. I'm curious if it uses IE rendering engine, or some custom rendering engine. (It sounds like it might use a custom one, based on the differences.)

One thing you could try is setting the border to 'thin', and then having a separate CSS rule inside a Conditional IE statement. See [QuirksMode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for more information on IE Conditionals.

So it could be:

```
<style>
   table { border: thin solid black; }
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style>
   table { border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works... *untested*:

Set the main CSS to `thin` so that the Excel report has a `1px border` and then use a conditional comment to target IE for the `1px border`

```
<!--[if IE]>
    //style rule for `border:1px` etc.
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the border to thin. And add

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

to your declaration. Should fix the 2px issue in IE